# General Guidance- retropi

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange post: [Making a Retro Game-General Guidance](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132665/making-a-retro-game-general-guidance)

So I took the tour and definitely asked my question (link above) in the wrong place but maybe this is the right place to post it? If I'm doing anything wrong or need to expand the question please let me know and I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe this is the right place to post it?

No; a more appropriate place would be https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/
or https://forums.raspberrypi.com/

I noticed when writing this that the comment I used when closing your question included *'read "What types of questions should I avoid asking?", noting the part "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."'*

Unfortunately that's actually been removed from our help section, so I will provide some context.  We expect questions to be clear, focussed, and specific enough that there could be a **singular** answer no more than a few paragraphs.  By "singular", I mean one single such answer, not a collection of them, such that somebody writes one to answer part of your question and someone else another to answer another part and so on.  If that's implied, you need to break it into a number of **separate** questions, and by "separate" I mean not written and presented in a single Q&A (question and answer).

If you think of SE (= Stack Exchange, the network that includes us, Stack Overflow, various other sites) as a set of *Q&A* sites as opposed to *discussion forums*, it may help, particularly if you are used to the latter.  Reddit and the official Rpi forum linked above are discussion style sites -- someone posts a topic with a question and people post responses one after another, possibly including responses to previous responses and so on, potentially for many pages.

If you look around a bit here you should get the general idea, and it is not that.  Going back to your question, the crux of the problem is here:

> Any recommendations for this [hardware] list, as well as what tutorials and resources I can use to learn what I need to get this accomplished

This is very very open ended, and very very general.  You refer to both assembling the device and coding it in python, but there is no specific question -- for example:

- [Can I connect RaspberryPi GPIO to Nintendo DS Buttons?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100467/can-i-connect-raspberrypi-gpio-to-nintendo-ds-buttons)
- [Capture keypress from Minecraft Pi in Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/capture-keypress-from-minecraft-pi-in-python)

These are specific questions, one about using hardware for a game oriented device and another about game programming in python.

My advice to you is that you take your discussion to reddit or the official Rpi forum to gather whatever big picture/random comment information you want, and then *start at the beginning* (which will be learning python, for which you don't need any hardware other than a computer).  With regard to tutorials, etc., generally these kinds of resources are easy enough to find with an internet search -- a [google search for `"game programming" python raspberry`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22game+programming%22+python+raspberry) yields me 220,000+ hits, at least a thousand or so of which I am sure are actually relevant and useful.<sup>1</sup>

So, there is already probably enough information out there on this topic for you to spend the rest of your life reading it.  You certainly don't have to ask people to write more, or to do something you can easily do yourself (search for python programming tutorials, etc).  Which brings us to another important point: *You are expected to make, and demonstrate that you have made, an effort at research yourself **first**.*  In other words, don't start your research by asking a question here, research the question as best you can and when you hit a point you are confused by, then consider asking someone else to take time out to help you.

Finally, as a research tip: The search I linked earlier was for `"game programming" python raspberry`.  Often you may want to search for "linux" instead of (or as well as) "raspberry (pi)" for a couple of reasons:

- The Pi is a fairly normal, general purpose computer that runs GNU/Linux; almost certainly you will be using some form of it.  Consider if you were writing a game for MS Windows: Would you then search for "game programming Acer laptop" because you have an Acer laptop?  **What's usually most, or only, relevant with this kind of stuff is the operating system.** And the various linux flavours are very similiar in this context, so you don't have to research Ubuntu specifically etc.<sup>2</sup>
- Linux has been around for much longer and is much more widely used than the Raspberry Pi, and so there is a greater breadth and depth of information around about it.

In this regard our bigger sibling on the SE network, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), may be useful, and for general programming of course the grand-pappy site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

---

1. Of course that's me on my computer, having already spent 8-9 years googling raspberry pi things, and as we know google likes to algorithmicly tailor responses. But you should still get a decent amount of relevant material.
2. BTW, consensus here is that we strongly recommend newbies use the official Raspberry Pi OS. Although again it isn't all that different from other linux distros, it is what most people here and in the Pi community are most familiar with, hence the easiest to get help with (not to mention the fact that it is the best adapted to the specific hardware).

Comment: Goldilocks, thank you for your answer it's exactly what I needed. I definitely did a bad job demonstrating the research I've done on the topic and will do better to improve on that in the future. You have been extremely thorough and helpful and I appreciate the time you've taken to answer my questions here. I'll be back soon with more questions written in the way you've said. Thank you again.